# Makefile dependency rules for multiple source-object compilation

Tags: makefile

I apologize if this is a somewhat noobish question, I have been searching for a while and haven't found the answer.

I am new to makefiles, and am trying to create one which compiles multiple source files in various directories into object files in a single directory and then link them.

It works, but it always recompiles all the files even if I haven't changed them. To my understanding, it should only do this if the dependencies are older than the targets. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = mpic++
CCU = nvcc

ARCH = -arch=sm_52

SOURCEDIR = ./source
SOLVERDIR = $(SOURCEDIR)/solvers
OBJECTDIR = ./bin

INCLUDE   = -I./include -I/home/alexander/.openmpi/include -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include

LIBRARY   = -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -lcublas -lcudart

OUT = cgsolve

CDEPS = $(OBJECTDIR)/main.o $(OBJECTDIR)/timer.o $(OBJECTDIR)/cgMPIFuncs.o

compileC: $(CDEPS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOURCEDIR)/main.cpp -o $(OBJECTDIR)/main.o
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOURCEDIR)/timer.cpp -o $(OBJECTDIR)/timer.o
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOURCEDIR)/cgMPIFuncs.cpp -o $(OBJECTDIR)/cgMPIFuncs.o

CUDEPS = $(OBJECTDIR)/BiCGStab.o $(OBJECTDIR)/CG.o $(OBJECTDIR)/solverUtil.o $(OBJECTDIR)/cudaKernels.o

compileCU: $(CUDEPS)
    $(CCU) $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOLVERDIR)/BiCGStab.cu -o $(OBJECTDIR)/BiCGStab.o
    $(CCU) $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOLVERDIR)/CG.cu -o $(OBJECTDIR)/CG.o
    $(CCU) $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOURCEDIR)/solverUtil.cu -o $(OBJECTDIR)/solverUtil.o
    $(CCU) $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -c $(SOURCEDIR)/cudaKernels.cu -o $(OBJECTDIR)/cudaKernels.o

OBJDEPS = $(OBJECTDIR)/main.o $(OBJECTDIR)/BiCGStab.o $(OBJECTDIR)/CG.o $(OBJECTDIR)/solverUtil.o $(OBJECTDIR)/cudaKernels.o $(OBJECTDIR)/timer.o $(OBJECTDIR)/cgMPIFuncs.o

build:
    $(CC) $(OBJDEPS) $(LIBRARY) -o $(OUT)

all: compileC compileCU build
```

And again, sorry if this is a repeat or something. I haven't been able to find a previous version of this question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting rules explicitly altogether, please try pattern-rule like below, also it's better to add OBJDEPS as pre-requisite for build target (then no need for compileC and compileCU, unless you want to keep those targets)

```
compileC: $(CDEPS)

compileCU: $(CUDEPS)

build: $(OBJDEPS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LIBRARY) -o $(OUT)

$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o :  $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o : $(SOLVERDIR)/%.cu
    $(CCU) $(ARCH) $(INCLUDE) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Good example, I figured out how makefiles work from this. This would be a lot easier if the examples online were less cryptic. Thanks a lot!